# What type of offset/ scaling would be good?

Tags: polynomials

The following graph is a sensor measurement.

[Scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPfAt.jpg)

The data points are also available in this [excel file.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GafHDTJ79Orz4-2cjIqWjFw98Fi8tRMU/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114447384456607145481&rtpof=true&sd=true) I want to do some offset correction/scaling to make the measured points match the actual points.
What is the simplest algorithm to do computationally by programming language like Python or MATLAB.

These data are acquired in MATLAB continuously point by point, and I have to apply these offset to each point. Will something like finding a linear fit for all possible points and multiplying it with a polynomial work? or if there are any better methods, please suggest.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just  in a spreadsheet you can do a linear fit.  If you plot them the other way, with measured horizontal, the slope of the line gives how much the actual rises for each unit of measured and the intercept is the offset yo want.  There are also linear fit routines in any language you want.